# Styling a component passed by props with emotion in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I am passing a component via props like:

```
const someicon = <SomeIcon>
..
<Sidebar icon={someicon} />
```

Then styling it with emotion/styled like:

```
const StyledIcon = styled(props.icon)`
  ...
`;
```

But the StyledIcon I am getting is a object:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), defaultProps: undefined, __emotion_real: {…}, __emotion_base: {…}, render: ƒ, …}$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref)defaultProps: undefinedrender: ƒ (props, ref)withComponent: ƒ (nextTag, nextOptions)__emotion_base: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}__emotion_forwardProp: undefined__emotion_real: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), defaultProps: undefined, __emotion_real: {…}, __emotion_base: {…}, render: ƒ, …}__emotion_styles: (4) ["label:StyledAppIcon;", "color:", ƒ, ";width:2em;height:2em;/*# sourceMappingURL=data:ap…1cblxuZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgU2lkZWJhcjtcbiJdfQ== */"]displayName: (...)toString: ƒ value()get displayName: ƒ ()set displayName: ƒ (name)__proto__: Object
```

I can't figure out what is going on here and how to properly pass components via props, then style them and then render them.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you write `StyledIcon` in JSX?

Comment: Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, defaultProps, __emotion_real, __emotion_base, __emotion_styles, __emotion_forwardProp, withComponent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Btw, I found that by passing components with className like <SomeIcon className=" icon" /> and then applying styles for this class in the sidebar component also works. Now just need to pass classes, at least saved repetitive styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) only works for **components** so you have to pass the icon as a component (at least a function that returns JSX):

```
const someicon = () => <SomeIcon>
```

Also, you have to forward the `className` prop:

```
const someicon = ({ className }) => <SomeIcon className={className}>
```

If your icon component contains no more template than `<SomeIcon />`, then no need to wrap it, simply write this:

```
<Sidebar icon={SomeIcon} />
```

And make sure that the `className` is properly retrieved from the props and set on a DOM element inside the `SomeIcon` component, because [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) works with classes under the hood.

**Note:** this is actually not a good practice to declare a styled component inside another component as it will be computed on every render cycle, and will display this warning:

> The component Styled(icon) with the id of "sc-iqAclL" has been created
> dynamically. You may see this warning because you've called styled
> inside another component. To resolve this only create new
> StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.